# Flask models: access extra properties of many to many relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

In my models.py in a flask app, I have the following tables:

```
class PackageBuild(db.Model, helpers.Serializer):
    __tablename__ = "package_build"

    package_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('package.id'))
    build_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('build.id'))
    git_hash = db.Column(db.Text)
    version = db.Column(db.Text)


class Build(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    packages = db.relationship(
        'Package',
        secondary='package_build',
        back_populates='builds'
    )


class Package(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    builds = db.relationship(
        'Build',
        secondary='package_build',
        back_populates='packages'
    )
```

I know I can access properties of the related table:

```
build.packages[0].id
```

But how can I access properties (e.g. git_hash) of the intermediate table (ideally by using build instance)?